# MobX React: Define a observer hook

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to define my own hooks in a MobX project which depend on mobx observables.
But it's not possible to wrap a hook with observer() because observer() must return a component.
Is there a way to define observer hooks?

Example:

```
// not working because observer must return a component
const useFindSuggestion = observer(({ target, node, suggestionsStore }: LinkSuggestionWrapperProps) => {
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState<IDocumentInfo[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const suggestions = suggestionsStore.getRelevantSuggestions(node, target).filter((s) => s.documentId !== node.target);
    setSuggestions(suggestions);
  }, []);

  return { suggestions };
});
```

Comment: No need to do anything special, just make it regular hook and then use inside component that is wrapped with `observer`

Comment: @Danila The useEffect within the hook gets not triggered because the dependencies are mobx observables.  Adding the dependencies to the dependency array does not work.

Comment: Well, it should work in normal situation! Could you maybe create some reproduction on https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: @Danila
https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-mobx-react-project-forked-8gnxgt 

With: [value, value.timer] -> works, because timer is a immutable and enforces evaluate.

Comment: That's exactly how you do it, yes, `[value.timer]` as dependency because that's the thing you care about. What is the question then again? :) You can do the same thing for your original hook - add relevant fields as dependencies.

Comment: Found the solution. Needed autorun()  :-)
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#useeffect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: use autorun within hook
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#useeffect

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-mobx-react-project-forked-8gnxgt?file=/index.js